# Cocompleteness of the category of small $A_\infty$ categories

Tags: a-infinity-algebras, homological-algebra

To follow up on my previous question, is the category of small $A_\infty$ categories even cocomplete? Looking for reference.

Comment: The 1-category of small $A_\infty$ categories is certainly cocomplete, as it is the category of representations of a Lawvere algebraic theory and hence presentable.  But this is, of course, not the category that you care about.  Presumably, you care instead about some version of an $(\infty,2)$-category, since $A_\infty$ categories are some version of $(\infty,1)$-categories.

Comment: I actually do want the plain 1-category. Could you please give a reference? Sounds very interesting.